# terraform : creating a new instance or upgrade the existing one?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am trying to upgrade the google cloud composer. How does terraform recognize I want to upgrade the existing one or creating a new instance? Where do I specify it in tf file?

```
terraform {
  backend "gcs" {
    bucket  = "tf-state-prod"
    prefix  = "terraform/state"
  }
}
```

If I change the prefix to a different file path prefix  = "terraform/new_state" , it will create a new intance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TF stores the **current state** of infrastructure that it manages in a [state file](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/state/index.html). Any changes you will make to your TF code, will be compared to what is stored in the state file. Based of this, TF can decide what resources have changed, which were added and which were removed.

Comment: If i want to create a new google cloud composer 2.0 instance and keep the old one composer 1.0.  If I change the composer version in tf file, will this change create a new instance or upgrade the existing one?

Comment: @Dataflower I'm not sure what do you mean. Please update the question with your TF code and what you want to change.

Comment: If I change the prefix to a different file path prefix  = "terraform/new_state" , it will create a new intance?

Answer (score 1):

The code example you included here is for the backend configuration, which is a special part of the root module of a Terraform configuration because rather than declaring some infrastructure for Terraform to create, it instead tells Terraform where to store its metadata about the managed infrastructure.

If you change any part of the `backend "gcs"` block then you'll need to re-initialize your working directory using `terraform init`. When you do so, Terraform will notice that you changed the settings and by default will prompt you to decide whether you want to migrate the existing state snapshot to the new location.

If you intend to have more than one "latest" state snapshot from the same configuration then you may wish to use [Workspaces](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/state/workspaces.html) to achieve that, though be sure to consider the advice in [When to use Multiple Workspaces](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/state/workspaces.html#when-to-use-multiple-workspaces) to see if that's recommended as a suitable solution for whatever is your underlying goal. That section includes some alternative approaches that better suit some other situations.

Comment: Thank you so much.